# best practices to implement hashing?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, c#-3.0

I need to implement hashing **(I am not referring encryption)** to make some data fields **(passwords or some details that do not require getting back in original format, rather only need to match in db)** secure. Can you please suggest me the best practices to implement hashing. I will be using C# and SQL Server and it will be a web site.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? What data fields, and what are you securing them from?

Comment: you need to provide further info like what kind of data etc

Comment: make sure your not getting confused with encryption. When you hash something, you cannot un-hash it to get the data back. Hashing is mainly useful in terms of verifying content against a submitted hash, for example passwords etc.

Comment: Really?  Why does more detail need to be provided?  It seems reasonable to assume passwords.  And I feel pretty confident stepping out onto the limb and suggesting that the OP is attempting to protect this sensitive data from hackers.  Either that, or space aliens.

Comment: Yes, it matters. You can't just randomly throw encryption and cryptography at things and expect strong security to come out the other end. Good security requires an understanding of what you're trying to protect against: for starters, there's a big difference between protecting against casual compromise vs. guarding against malicious attackers.

Comment: @John, correct me if I'm wrong, but a solution that guards against malicious attackers will also guard against casual compromise, no?

Comment: There is no way to design a good security system when your requirements begin and end with "to make some data fields secure". Take passwords and credit card numbers, for example. They are secured in very different ways. We need details.

Comment: @John, you are confusing a spec with an SO question asking for guidance on best practices.

Comment: @John, @mqpasta, @Xhalent, I am referring passwords, kindly see my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK now you've said you're protecting passwords you have some options.

The .NET framework has some built in algorithms - MD5, SHA1, SHA2. MD5 and SHA1 are considered obsolete and dangerous now, instead stick to SHA256.

For example (taken from my book)

```
static byte[] GenerateSaltedHash(string password, byte[] salt)
{
  byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
  HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA256Managed();

  byte[] plainTextWithSaltBytes = 
    new byte[plainText.Length + salt.Length];

  for (int i = 0; i < plainText.Length; i++)
  {
    plainTextWithSaltBytes[i] = plainText[i];
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < salt.Length; i++)
  {
    plainTextWithSaltBytes[plainText.Length + i] = salt[i];
  }

  byte[] hash = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);            
}
```

Now the salt is there to stop precomputed lookups of hashes (hashing itself is not enough any more, people have precomputed hashes of dictionary words and more). But how do you get a salt? Well it's any unique value really, usually a random set of bytes.

```
    public byte[] GenerateSalt(int length)
    {
        salt = new byte[length];

        // Strong runtime pseudo-random number generator, on Windows uses CryptAPI
        // on Unix /dev/urandom
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        random.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);

        return salt;
    }
```

So you'd call GenerateSalt(32) first to get the salt (32 is just an example, longer if you wish. You will need to store the salt alongside the password - you don't need to worry about protecting it at all.

Finally you'll need a compare function. When you want to check passwords you would take the user input, get the salt for that user, generate the hash for the supplied password and stored salt, and then compare. You would do this using something like

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
public static bool ConstantCompare(byte[] array1, byte[] array2)
{
    const byte Zero = 0;
    int maxLength = array1.Length > array2.Length ? array1.Length : array2.Length;
    bool wereEqual = array1.Length == array2.Length;

    byte[] paddedArray1 = new byte[maxLength];
    byte[] paddedArray2 = new byte[maxLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        paddedArray1[i] = array1.Length > i ? array1[i] : Zero;
        paddedArray2[i] = array2.Length > i ? array2[i] : Zero;
    }
    bool compareResult = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
    {
        compareResult = compareResult & paddedArray1[i] == paddedArray2[i];
    }
    return compareResult & wereEqual;
}
```

I should, of course, point out the ASP.NET membership functions do salt and hash, so they should probably be a first point of call. No point in rolling your own if someone else has done the work.

Comment: Thanks @blowdart for sparing time and precious guidance.

I have not used ASP.net membership functions and classes. Can you please guide a little more what I should look to know for it ?

Thanks

Comment: Oh there's a whole book on the ASP.NET membership database, but basically it takes care of user registration for you. How you use it depends on WebForms or MVC. MSDN has an introduction at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx for WebForms and http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs has one for MVC

Answer (score 1):

Here is an API using PBKDF2 for key stretching ONTOP of hashing, this is now best practice.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pwdtknet

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what hashing is.  You don't use a hash to "make data fields secure", because a hash can only be calculated in one direction. Compute and store the hash for your data, store the hash only, and you will be unable to retrieve your data later.

You might need to *encrypt* the data.  That is an entirely different can of worms with it's own set of problems: how do you store and protect the decryption key, what encryption algorithm to use, do you do the encryption at the database level (sql server supports this) or the application level?  How do you enforce encrypted transfer, and protect against copy of the data by the end user?

Comment: Thanks @Joel, I have same idea about hashing and encryption differences as you explained. 

I was looking for best practices to implement hashing ? Like what algo should be used ? Should it be in C# or in SQL Server ? Any other practices to follow ?